# Creating a method to verify against a table

Tags: c#, winforms

Basically I'm trying to create a method which will take two arguments and run it against a table to determine the result and return it... The table is below

[image]

For example if the age is 16 and the score is 50 the method should return the rating as `GOOD`

The code structure I'm thinking of is something like this..

```
public void test(int age, int score)
        {
            while (age>=15 && age<=19 )
            {
              //code..
               break;

            }
        }
```

But just cant get it right... any ideas?

Comment: or use of `if` `else` statement is better choice rather than `while` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if value falls in a given range you need `&&` (instead of `||`) in the condition:

```
 lowerBound <= age && age <= upperBound
```

For the rest of the code use either hardcoded sequence of `if` conditions for each range (i.e. if performance is very important and probability of hitting particular range is significantly different between ranges) or just iteration over collection of age ranges/ result ranges (for this case consider to represent data as List of {age range, List or result range} )

Comment: Yh got that! but still how can i go about and accomplish what i originally wanted to?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Enumerable.Range(15,19).Contains(age))
{
   if (Enumerable.Range(0,30).Contains(score))
   {
   ...
   }
   else
   if (Enumerable.Range(31,38).Contains(score))
   {
   ...
   }
   else
   ...
}
else
if (Enumerable.Range(20,29).Contains(age))
{
....
}
else
if (Enumerable.Range(30,39).Contains(age))
{
....
}
else
....
```

Answer (score 1):

i would try to see if this would work properly

[online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yrrmSb)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    struct AgeScore
    {
        public MinMax Age;
        public MinMax Score;

        public AgeScore(MinMax Age, MinMax Score)
        {
            this.Age = Age;
            this.Score = Score;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Age {0} - Score {1}", Age, Score);
        }
    }
    struct MinMax
    {
        int min;
        int max;
        public bool Between(int num)
        {
            return num >= min && num <= max;
        }

        public MinMax(int min, int max)
        {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Range: {0}-{1}", min, max);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lookup = new Dictionary<string, AgeScore>();

            BuildRating(lookup);

            process(lookup, 16, 50);
            process(lookup, 16, 70);
            process(lookup, 45, 20);
            process(lookup, 10, 50);

            Console.Read();
        }

        static void BuildRating(Dictionary<string, AgeScore> rating)
        {
            //ONLY DOING A FEW FOR DEMO PURPOSE

            //age 15-19 score 60+
            rating.Add("EXCELLENT", new AgeScore(new MinMax(15, 19), new MinMax(60, int.MaxValue)));

            //age 15-19 score 45-59
            rating.Add("GOOD", new AgeScore(new MinMax(15, 19), new MinMax(45, 59)));

            //age 40-49 score <25
            rating.Add("POOR", new AgeScore(new MinMax(40, 49), new MinMax(int.MinValue, 24)));
        }

        static void process(Dictionary<string, AgeScore> rate, int age, int score)
        {
            var rating = rate.Where(x => x.Value.Age.Between(age) &&
                                         x.Value.Score.Between(score)).FirstOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine("For age {0} and score {1} you have this rating is {2}\n", age, score, string.IsNullOrEmpty(rating.Key) ? "Unrated" : rating.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```